# List of dictionaries to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[   defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                {   'account_id': '',
                    'address': {   'address_country': 'ZM',
                                   'city': 'North Matthewland',
                                   'state': 'Nevada',
                                   'street_name': 'Cabrera Extensions',
                                   'street_number': 197,
                                   'zip_code': '81431'},
                    'affiliate_id': 12,
                    'brand': 'TTT',
                    'country': 'ZM',
                    'email': 'rosariojohn@TTT.zed',
                    'first_name': 'Peter',
                    'last_name': 'Green',
                    'leadsource': 559,
                    'password': 'test385',
                    'phone_number': '052839601'},)]
```

In my situation, I need to put all this data to CSV file, so via csv module, I try to write all this data to CSV file but I receive every time 
error message:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'address'
```

So I add to 'fieldnames' address, but the problem is that I receive all data in one column of address.

```
with open('test_file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    filed_names = ['first_name',
                   'last_name',
                   'email',
                   'phone_number',
                   'password',
                   'country',
                   'leadsource',
                   'affiliate_id',
                   'account_id',
                   'brand',
                   'street_number',
                   'street_name',
                   'city',
                   'state',
                   'address_country',
                   'zip_code',
                   ]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=filed_names)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(list_user_details)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas offers a convenient alternative:

```
# first flatten address
for d in lst:
    d.update(d['address'])
    del d['address']

# read into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=range(len(lst)))

# output to csv
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

# Result
#   account_id address_country  affiliate_id brand               city country  \
# 0                         ZM            12   TTT  North Matthewland      ZM   

#                  email first_name last_name  leadsource password phone_number  \
# 0  rosariojohn@TTT.zed      Peter     Green         559  test385    052839601   

#     state         street_name  street_number zip_code  
# 0  Nevada  Cabrera Extensions            197    81431
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to flatten out the structure so it's just a list of dictionaries holding strings and numbers, rather than a list of dictionaries holding dictionaries of strings and numbers.

Assuming that you don't want to modify this list just for the writing step, make a new empty list.  Copy the dictionaries from one list to the other, but convert the `address` dictionary into a set of additional fields called `address.address_country`, `address.city`, `address.state` and so on.

Then use `csv` to write out this new list, and pass it the modified fieldnames.

Also don't forget to test with commas inside the field strings.